# Не работает phpize

Tags: unix, php

Здраствуйте!
Отказывается работать фунция phpize в любой папке.

```
iMac-Mac:extension mac$ phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

Подскажите что делать.

**UPD**
Спасибо за ответ, но вот что выдает:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Comment: Уточните операционную систему.

Comment: А как вы думаете, какая у iMac операционная система?

Comment: 1. То, что у вас система называется iMac еще не говорит о том, что там установлен Mac OS.
2. Почему тогда бы в теги не добавить это?
3. http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/02/install-the-latest-autoconf-and-automake-on-mac-os-10-6/

Answer (score 1):

> yum install autoconf

или

> sudo apt-get install autoconf

В зависимости от системы. И вопрос скорее на [руткод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).